# Undefined property during destructuring Regex groups

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am parsing a regEx which is including groups. In javascript, I am trying to destructure match.groups into the variables and getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'familyName' of undefined, js engine: hermes`.

The following is the snippet in React Native, I am trying to use:

```
const parseCode = data => {
    const payload = {};
    for (const match of data.matchAll(rgx)) {
      const {familyName, givenName, birthday} =
        match.groups;
      
      console.log(
        `familyName: ${familyName}  givenName:${givenName}  birthday: ${birthday}`);
    }
};
```

Updates:

I have the following [regex expression](https://regex101.com/r/RZ5xst/1) which I would to use in React Native and extract the groups defined in there such as FamilyName, GivenName, etc.

The following snippet is working on javascript playground:

```
const data= "%SPECIMEN,$TESTTHREE^910 FIRST ST$ALBERTA AB  V8W 3Y8^?;19900403?"

const rgx =
    /^%(?<track1>((?<FamilyName>\b[A-Z0-9\s.\-',]+)\$(?<GivenName>(?:[A-Z0-9\s.\-'])+)){0,35}\^((?<AddressLine1>\b[A-Z0-9\s.\-',]+)\$(?<AddressLine2>(?:[A-Z0-9\s.\-'])+)){0,29}\^)\?;(?<track2>(?<Birthday>\d{0,8}))\?/g;

//first implementation
const matches = data.matchAll(rgx);
let output1 = {};
for (const match of matches) {
  // console.log(match);
  output1.surname = match[4];
  output1.givenName = match[5];
  output1.birthday = match[14];
}
console.log("output1")
console.log(output1);

//second implementation
const output2 = Array.from(data.matchAll(rgx), ({groups}) => ({
  surname: groups?.FamilyName?.replace(/,\s*$/, '') || null,
  givenName: groups?.GivenName || null,
  birthday: groups?.Birthday || null,
}));

console.log('output2');
console.log(output2);
```

However, just the first implementation works using for loop to iterate over matches. In there I would like to use match.groups?.FamilyName for instance, but I am getting undefined and just the correct value when accessing through match[index]. How could I use the group names in the first implementation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code once :

```
const parseCode = data => {
    const rgx = /your-regex-pattern/g;
    
    const payload = Array.from(data.matchAll(rgx), ({ groups }) => ({
        familyName: groups?.familyName || null,
        givenName: groups?.givenName || null,
        birthday: groups?.birthday || null
    }));

    console.log(payload);
};
```

This provides compact and efficient handling of the matches while ensuring fallback values of null for missing groups.

Comment: Thanks @David Teo. Looks fantastic! I am having an issue when including it in React Native, not sure if something internal is giving trouble. I am able to get the appropriate data just when accessing to the index using match. I used group Names for better understanding of code. Would you know how to use groups when using for loop over matches?